# How can I change Bootstrap carousel indicators into dots?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4 Beta 2 version to do a carousel. The code looks like below:

```
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
                </ol>
```

And the carousel indicator show as lines: 
[image]

Is there a way I can change the indicators into dots instead of lines? I would assume it is an bootstrap option but I didn't find that relevant document. Do I need to write custom css for that?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, I think you need to write custom CSS for doing lines into dots.
You just need to override two properties (`width` and `height`) and add a new one, `border-radius`, to `.carousel-indicators li`.
Make `width` and `height` values equal eg: `10px` each and give a `border-radius` of `100%`.

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i just get rounded corners unless i do..not dots

Comment: Why does "" border-radius: 100% "" work when "" border-radius: <pixel unit> "' does not work?

Answer (score 9):

In bootstrap 5 if you change what's in the comments it works.

```
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 10px; /* change width */
    height: 10px; /* change height */
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .6s ease;
    border-radius: 100%; // /* add border-radius */
}
```

Example: [image of dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR9KX.jpg)

Comment: OP question is for bootstrap 4

Comment: @Sfili_81: Yes. But Bootstrap 5 wasn’t available when the OP asked the question. Offering an updated answer based on subsequent versions seems valuable to the community moving forward.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyCaney. I actually was looking for a solution for BS5 and came up with this post so I thought why not sharing a solution for anyone like me.

Answer (score 3):

I had to include .carousel for it to work properly.

```
.carousel .carousel-indicators li {
   width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the icon path in case you have one, using the inspect element you can get the class name. I used Mozilla to get the class name and then I used two svg icons for changing the default icons to custom icons.

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {

    background-image: url("images/carousel/back.svg");

}

.carousel-control-next-icon {

    background-image: url("images/carousel/next.svg");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must override the inline style using the word !important. This overrides any other styling that the element has.

I was able to style the indicators into circles with a bluish color by doing the following:

```
.carousel-indicators button {
    height: 10px !important;
    width: 10px !important;
    margin: 0 10px !important;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #1963ac !important;
}
```

The modern Bootstrap carousel is now laying them out as buttons.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
        width: 1rem;
        height: 1rem;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
    }
    
    .carousel-indicators .active {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for big circle:

```css
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now at Bootstrap V5.3
The Carousel Indicators " changed to be "button" not "ol" anymore
so to Change Bootstrap V5.3 Carousel Indicators into dots?

This how it looks at the HTML

```
<div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
```

all you need to do to change it to Dots

Write this at CSS

```
.carousel-indicators .active {
     background: white !important;
}

#carouselExampleCaptions .carousel-indicators button {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background: transparent;
}
```

and now you got dots with white background for active slide and transparent background for the rest

I hope this help.